# Acumatica throwing a 500 Server Exception when refreshing the OAuth 2 Access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, acumatica

I'm receiving a 500 Server Exception when the Refresh Token for OAuth 2 takes place. How do I go about resolving this exception? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

The full exception message is:

```
Unhandled exception accessing: /identity/connect/token
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.<ValidateRefreshTokenRequestAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.<RunValidationAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.System.Web.Http910911.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

**Some more detail:**

- We're making use of a web-based integration service called [Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/). The service fully supports the OAuth 1 & 2 protocols.
- We've configured the client application on the **Connected Applications** screen using the `Authorization Code` flow, and we're able to get the initial authorization working. i.e. we're receiving the access token and are able to make subsequent API calls using the Contract-Based REST API.
- The issue comes in when the initial access token expires.

  - We have already reached out to Integromat's support team and they are also not able to see anything obvious wrong with the request being sent through on the refresh token phase.
  - Note we have reviewed & compared the below with this [help article](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff780860-09c2-46c9-bdd7-c6c3b1fc442c).

Below is an overview of the OAuth setup in Integromat:

```json
{
    "authorize": {
        "qs": {
            "scope": "{{join(oauth.scope, ' ')}}", -- this basically equates to api%20offline_access
            "client_id": "{{ifempty(parameters.clientId, common.clientId)}}",
            "redirect_uri": "{{oauth.redirectUri}}",
            "response_type": "code"
        },
        "url": "https://our-instance/identity/connect/authorize",
        "response": {
            "temp": {
                "code": "{{query.code}}"
            }
        }
    },
    "token": {
        "url": "https://our-instance/identity/connect/token",
        "method": "POST",
        "body": {
            "code": "{{temp.code}}",
            "client_id": "{{ifempty(parameters.clientId, common.clientId)}}",
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "redirect_uri": "{{oauth.redirectUri}}",
            "client_secret": "{{ifempty(parameters.clientSecret, common.clientSecret)}}"
        },
        "type": "urlencoded",
        "response": {
            "data": {
                "expires": "{{addSeconds(now, body.expires_in)}}",
                "accessToken": "{{body.access_token}}",
                "refreshToken": "{{body.refresh_token}}"
            },
            "expires": "{{addSeconds(now, body.expires_in)}}"
        },
        "log": {
            "sanitize": ["request.body.code", "request.body.client_secret", "response.body.access_token", "response.body.refresh_token"]
        }
    },
    "refresh": {
        "condition": "{{data.expires < addMinutes(now, 60)}}",
        "url": "https://our-instance/identity/connect/token",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer {{connection.accessToken}}"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "body": {
            "client_id": "{{ifempty(parameters.clientId, common.clientId)}}",
            "grant_type": "refresh_token",
            "client_secret": "{{ifempty(parameters.clientSecret, common.clientSecret)}}",
            "refresh_token": "{{data.refreshToken}}"
        },
        "type": "urlencoded",
        "response": {
            "data": {
                "expires": "{{addSeconds(now, body.expires_in)}}",
                "accessToken": "{{body.access_token}}"
            },
            "expires": "{{addSeconds(now, body.expires_in)}}"
        },
        "log": {
            "sanitize": ["request.body.code", "request.body.client_secret", "response.body.access_token", "response.body.refresh_token"]
        }
    },
    "info": {
        "url": "https://our-instance/entity/SIH/18.200.001/Currency/",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer {{connection.accessToken}}"
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "response": {
            "uid": "{{body.id}}",
            "metadata": {
                "type": "text",
                "value": "{{body.user}}"
            }
        },
        "log": {
            "sanitize": ["request.headers.authorization"]
        }
    },
    "invalidate": {
        "url": "https://our-instance/entity/auth/logout",
        "headers": {
            "authorization": "Bearer {{connection.accessToken}}"
        },
        "log": {
            "sanitize": ["request.headers.authorization"]
        }
    }
}
```

Some additional **Request Profile** logs on the /identity/connect/token can be seen below:

[image: trace]

The **FirstChanceException** is as follows:

```
You are not currently logged in.

Stack Trace:

   at PX.Data.PXFirstChanceExceptionLogger.a(Object A_0, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs A_1)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.c()
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.getCompanyID(String tableName, companySetting& setting)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.GetSlot[ObjectType](String key, PrefetchDelegate`1 prefetchDelegate, Type[] tables)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabase.GetSlot[ObjectType](String key, Type[] tables)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.b(Type A_0)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance(Type graphType, String prefix)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance(Type graphType)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance[Graph]()
   at PX.Owin.IdentityServerIntegration.TokenStoreBase`2.GetImpl(String key)
   at PX.Owin.IdentityServerIntegration.TokenStoreBase`2.GetAsync(String key)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.<ValidateRefreshTokenRequestAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.ValidateRefreshTokenRequestAsync(NameValueCollection parameters)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.<RunValidationAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.RunValidationAsync(Func`2 validationFunc, NameValueCollection parameters)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator.ValidateRequestAsync(NameValueCollection parameters, Client client)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.ProcessAsync(NameValueCollection parameters)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController.Post()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass12.<GetExecutor>b__8(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(ActionInvoker innerInvoker)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<>c__DisplayClass10`1.<InvokeActionWithActionFilters>b__f()
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthorizationFilterResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.Owin.DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.InvokeCore(IOwinContext context, IOwinRequest owinRequest, IOwinResponse owinResponse)
   at Owin.SignOutMessageCookieExtension.<<ConfigureSignOutMessageCookie>b__0>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.SignOutMessageCookieExtension.<ConfigureSignOutMessageCookie>b__0(IOwinContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Owin.UseCookieAuthenticationExtension.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<ConfigureCookieAuthentication>b__6>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.UseCookieAuthenticationExtension.<>c__DisplayClass9.<ConfigureCookieAuthentication>b__6(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Owin.OwinExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<UseAutofacMiddleware>b__0>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.OwinExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2.<UseAutofacMiddleware>b__0(IOwinContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Owin.ConfigureRenderLoggedOutPageExtension.<<ConfigureRenderLoggedOutPage>b__0>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.ConfigureRenderLoggedOutPageExtension.<ConfigureRenderLoggedOutPage>b__0(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at Owin.ConfigureRequestBodyBufferExtension.<<ConfigureRequestBodyBuffer>b__0>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.ConfigureRequestBodyBufferExtension.<ConfigureRequestBodyBuffer>b__0(IOwinContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Owin.ConfigureIdentityServerIssuerExtension.<>c__DisplayClass5.<<ConfigureIdentityServerIssuer>b__1>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.ConfigureIdentityServerIssuerExtension.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ConfigureIdentityServerIssuer>b__1(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at Owin.ConfigureIdentityServerBaseUrlExtension.<>c__DisplayClass1.<<ConfigureIdentityServerBaseUrl>b__0>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.ConfigureIdentityServerBaseUrlExtension.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ConfigureIdentityServerBaseUrl>b__0(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at Owin.ConfigureRequestIdExtension.<<ConfigureRequestId>b__0>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.ConfigureRequestIdExtension.<ConfigureRequestId>b__0(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting.RequireSslMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting.RequireSslMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 env)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at PX.Owin.Startup.<>c.<<ConfigurationImpl>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at PX.Owin.Startup.<>c.<ConfigurationImpl>b__10_0(IOwinContext ctx, Func`1 n)
   at Owin.AutofacAppBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<RegisterAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Owin.AutofacAppBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<RegisterAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector>b__0(IOwinContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.RunApp(Func`2 entryPoint, IDictionary`2 environment, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, StageAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Comment: Which version of Acumatica are you using? I believe this is a bug that was fixed in 2020R1 Update 1.

Comment: Hi @SergRogovtsev, we are currently on 19.100.0122.

Comment: did you try to reuse the refresh token?

Comment: Hi @samol518, yes we have. We have since changed the Auth Flow to Resource Owner and it seems like that option is working so far. Will keep you guys posted.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the fact that you are trying to use the refresh token multiple time.

Each refresh token can only be used a single time.

Once a refresh token is used it provides you with a new token and a new refresh token. The refresh token that you have just used becomes obsolete and you need to use the new one in order to get a new token/refresh token combo.